# Why this simple regexp doesn't work when CLOB size > 4KB?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, clob

```
declare
  c clob := '0123456789ABCDEF';
begin
  c := c||c||c||c; c := c||c||c||c;
  c := c||c||c||c; c := c||c||c||c;
  -- Now length(c) = 4096
  c := regexp_substr(c, '(.*)\1'); --ERROR:No more data to read from socket. Why?
end;
```

Is [it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29422) a bug?

It works fine when using `varchar2` instead of `clob`.

Comment: Sounds like it; does the alert log say why the server session died? SQL Fiddle uses 11.2.0.2 so maybe it's fixed in a later patch set, unless you're already using one...

Comment: I agree this smacks of being a bug. Note, however, that if the pattern is changed to something that returns fewer characters [(as in this SQLFiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d53dc/4) it works fine - thus, it seems that REGEXP_SUBSTR may be having problems with the length of the returned substring. Also note that this could be a problem with SQLFiddle itself. I don't have a local Oracle instance to toy with here - if someone does and could report back, I'm sure we'd all appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably convinced this is a bug in Oracle, and is related to the specific regular expression used.  [In this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d53dc/12) I played around with CLOBs of varying length, returning strings of varying length, and the only regular expression I found (in my very much non-exhaustive test) was the one supplied by OP. The code from the SQLFiddle is:

```
create table temp_output(s varchar2(4000));

declare
  c16   clob := '0123456789ABCDEF';
  c64   clob;
  c256  clob;
  c1k   clob;
  c4k   clob;
  c4kp2 clob;  -- 4096 with 'x' at each end
  c4kwx clob;  -- 4095 with 'x' at each end
  c16k  clob;
  c16kwx  clob;  -- 16k with x's embedded
  x     clob := 'x';
  d     clob;
begin
  c64  := c16  || c16  || c16  || c16;
  c256 := c64  || c64  || c64  || c64;
  c1k  := c256 || c256 || c256 || c256;
  c4k  := c1k  || c1k  || c1k  || c1k;
  c4kp2 := x || c4k || x;
  c4kwx := x || SUBSTR(c4k, 1, 4093) || x;  -- 4095 chars total
  c16k := c4k  || c4k  || c4k || c4k;
  c16kwx := c4k || x || c4k || c4k || x || c4k;

  insert into temp_output(s) values ('LENGTH(c4k)=' || LENGTH(c4k));
  insert into temp_output(s) values ('LENGTH(c16k)=' || LENGTH(c16k));

  -- d := regexp_substr(c4kp2, '(.*)\1');  -- ERROR
  -- d := regexp_substr(c4kp2, 'x.*x');  -- No error
  d := regexp_substr(c16kwx, 'x.*x');  -- No error

  insert into temp_output (s) values ('LENGTH(d)=' || LENGTH(d));
  insert into temp_output (s) values (SUBSTR(d, 1, 4000));
end;
/
select * from temp_output
/
```

My original thinking was that perhaps there was an unpublished limit to the amount of text which could be extracted by the regexp, but that did not turn out to be correct.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This problem seems to appear only for regexps containing lengthy backreferences (longer than 4K).